# Google charts' addRows() function does not want to accept an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-visualization

I am trying to make a line chart, but Google Charts keeps throwing this error when I try to add a row of data:

> Error: Every row given must be either null or an array. @ ...corechart.I.js:162

Here are some example columns I tried. Making the columns works fine, and displays an empty graph as long as I don't add any rows.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('number', 'timestamp');
        data.addColumn('number', 'JPY');
        data.addColumn('number', 'EUR');
        data.addColumn('number', 'SEK');
        data.addColumn('number', 'HKD');
        data.addColumn('number', 'CHF');
//So far so good
```

Now, no matter how I try to pass an array with addRows(), I get the error. I have found similar questions here, but they've all failed for reasons of malformed code or used a different methodology to pass the code in. So here is a simplified test case, which still fails.

```
data.addRows([1,2,3,4,5,6]); //Breaks the chart
```

I also tried:

```
var myrow = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
data.addRows(myrow);
```

I don't see how I can make this any more literally an array. I also passed two at once, because all the example code seems to pass multiple rows.

```
data.addRows([1,2,3,4,5,6],
             [7,8,9,10,11,12]);
```

Still fails.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Easy one.  The addRows() method expects you to provide an array of arrays, not a single array for one row, and not separate parameters for each row.  See [the example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_addRows) in the docs.  Fixing your example, it should look like this:

```
data.addRows([[1,2,3,4,5,6], [7,8,9,10,11,12]]);
```

You might also prefer to use the addRow() method, which takes just one row at a time.

Comment: Thanks! addRow() is more convenient for my case as well, thanks for that too.

Answer (score 2):

I had same trouble while I was adding rows using for loop, but then you could find in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_insertRows) itself, addRows() expect array of Arrays, the thing you're trying to do can be achieved with simple addRow() without an 'S'.
`addRow([1,2,3,4,5,6])`